# Triggering a CSS animation with Jquery

Tags: jquery, button, triggers, css-animations

I've got a CSS animation that I'd like to trigger by clicking on the button and for it then to link to another page. Is there also a way for the animation to not play as soon as the page loads? Thanks in advance!

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Test.css">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".main-btn").mouseup(function(){
   $(".wrapper").reload();
  });
});
</script>

</head>

<body bgcolor="#00CCFF">

<a href="http://www.google.com" class="main-btn">
    <div class="btn-txt">
        <p>click</p>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper" data-anim="base wrapper">      
        <div class="circle" data-anim="base left"></div>
        <div class="circle" data-anim="base right"></div>
    </div>
</a>

</html>

@charset "UTF-8";


.main-btn {
    opcacity:1.0;
    position:absolute;
    width:172px;
    height:172px;
}

.main-btn:hover {
    opacity:0.7;
}

.btn-txt {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    z-index:-100;
    text-align:center;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:-10px;
    top:11%;
    font-family:Arial;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    color:#FFF;
    font-size:2.5em;    
}


.wrapper {
  width: 172px; /* Set the size of the progress bar */
  height: 172px;
  position: absolute;/* Enable clipping */
  clip: rect(0px, 172px, 172px, 78.5px); /* Hide half of the progress bar */
}
/* Set the sizes of the elements that make up the progress bar */




.circle {
  width: 155px;
  height:155px;
  border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 86px;
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(0px, 78.5px, 172px, 0px);
}

/* Using the data attributes for the animation selectors. */
/* Base settings for all animated elements */
div[data-anim~=base] {
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;  /* Only run once */
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards; /* Hold the last keyframe */
  -webkit-animation-timing-function:linear; /* Linear animation */
}

.wrapper[data-anim~=wrapper] {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.01s; /* Complete keyframes asap */
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.25s; /* Wait half of the animation */
  -webkit-animation-name: close-wrapper; /* Keyframes name */
}

.circle[data-anim~=left] {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s; /* Full animation time */
  -webkit-animation-name: left-spin;
}

.circle[data-anim~=right] {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.25s; /* Half animation time */
  -webkit-animation-name: right-spin;
}

/* Rotate the right side of the progress bar from 0 to 180 degrees */
@-webkit-keyframes right-spin {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
}
/* Rotate the left side of the progress bar from 0 to 360 degrees */
@-webkit-keyframes left-spin {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
/* Set the wrapper clip to auto, effectively removing the clip */
@-webkit-keyframes close-wrapper {
  to {
    clip: rect(auto, auto, auto, auto);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your questions seems a bit confused, the two parts are at cross purposes...:

> I've got a CSS animation that I'd like to trigger by clicking on the
>   button and for it then to link to another page.

So you want an animation to run and *then* load a page?

This can be achieved with, e.g.:

```
$('a').on('click',function(e){ // click the link
    e.preventDefault(); // stop the default immediate redirect
    $(this).addClass('animationClass'); // add the animation class
    setTimeout(function(){
        // do something after 1000ms (or same as animation duration)
    },1000);
});
```

Where `animationClass` is the class which you can apply to animate your link.

> Is there also a way for the animation to not play as soon as the page
>   loads?

So you want to load the page and *then* animate after a period of time?

[**Simply use `animation-delay`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-delay)

> The animation-delay CSS property specifies when the animation should
>   start. This lets the animation sequence begin some time after it's
>   applied to an element.